# Laravel 7 add a value check to middleware verified?

Tags: php, laravel

I used middleware('verified') to ask to new user to confirm mail :

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');
```

That's working great.

If the mail is verified, I would like to check if the is_active field is equal to 1 (and not 0) because we need to accept or deny new registerations.

Have I to add an own middleware or modify the verified one ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said Omer Yilmaz, the best way is to create a new middleware (customized) :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(auth()->user()->is_active != 0)
    { 
        return $next($request); 
    } 
    return redirect('/'); 
}
```

and in web.php, I call both middlewares, verified has the priority :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified', 'checkuserisactive');
```

Don't forget to declare your new middleware in the kernel.php file :

App/Http/Kernel.php

```
'checkuserisactive' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserIsActive::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to duplicated emails on your system until mail verification. This may be mistake
1. remove unique from email on users table. 
2. modify registration rules
3. after email verification delete other users with same email

or:
Delete user (if has not verify email with same email) before register new user

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  No, If a new user is registered, he has to valide his email by clicking on the link (recevied by mal).  From a form, we have to accept or deny the new registration.  Either it's OK, is_active field will be 1, otherwhise, it will be 0 and the user will not enter into the site.

Comment: public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if(auth()->user()->is_active != 0){
    return $next($request);
  }
  return redirect('home')->with('error','Permission Denied!!! Your account is not active.');
}

Comment: Hi Omer, THANK YOU, I'm going to try your code.  Do you think it's better to create a new middleware ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, may be yo dont want to use this sometimes on some users, so new middleware is best solution

Comment: Thank you Omer.  You can rely and I will validate your reply.